# Why does GNU Info have so many key sequences for the same command?

Tags: gnu

Why does GNU Info (info-stdn) have so many key sequences for the same command ? eg.:

```
C-f                             (forward-char)    Move forward a character
ESC  O C                        (forward-char)    Move forward a character
ESC  [ C                        (forward-char)    Move forward a character

ESC  ESC  O B .. ESC  ESC  O C  (forward-word)    Move forward a word
ESC  ESC  [ B                   (forward-word)    Move forward a word
ESC f                           (forward-word)    Move forward a word

SPC                                               Scroll forward a page
C-v                             (scroll-forward)  Scroll forward in this window
ESC  [  6 ~                     (scroll-forward)  Scroll forward in this window
```

Here is my GNU Info version:

```
[root@localhost ~]# info --version
info (GNU texinfo) 4.0

Copyright (C) 1999 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
There is NO warranty.  You may redistribute this software
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the files named COPYING.
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: Are you asking why a program would have more than one shortcut for the same thing in general, or why GNU Info has these specific shortcuts in particular?

Comment: @user1686 Well I imagine programs could provide different ways to arrive at the same function depending on current user context (eg. to avoid conflicting key sequences between different dialogs and menus). But GNU Info's key sequences seem very similar in the same context (eg. whether in normal view mode or the Echo Area, I found it highly peculiar to have 3 different key sequences to do the same thing).

Answer (score 2):

Each action has shortcuts from two worlds – a "PC-style" shortcut and an "Emacs-style" shortcut.

For example, `C-f` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> is [the Emacs key](https://kb.mit.edu/confluence/display/istcontrib/Moving+the+Cursor+without+the+mouse+in+emacs) for moving the cursor forward; similarly `ESC f` is actually a different way to write `M-f` <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> which might be Emacs-ese for jumping to the next word.

(You'll also find many of these shortcuts in Bash, where they're grouped under "emacs-mode". They well predate Emacs usage on "modern" PC keyboards with arrows and PgUp/PgDn keys, similar to why Vi/Vim has `hjkl` navigation – which it retains despite *also* supporting modern arrow keys.)

Meanwhile, `ESC [ C` is not a multi-key sequence – it represents *one* key, specifically the <kbd>→</kbd> "Right arrow" cursor key, and `ESC [ 6 ~` is sent when you press <kbd>Page Down</kbd> in a terminal emulator.

There are two of each because of inconsistency across terminal emulators – variants with `ESC O` are also arrow keys, but in a format specific to the Rxvt terminal, while `ESC [` is used by most other terminal emulators (Xterm-style). So the two entries are really the same user-facing keypress, but transmitted differently.

(There are more inconsistencies besides that; sequence `ESC [ B` would, on its own, mean <kbd>←</kbd> "Left arrow"; your specific example with an additional `ESC` in front turns it into <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>. This again varies – in Xterm's "modifier" format, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> would be `ESC [ 1 ; 3 C`, therefore GNU Info would need to recognize both sequences in order to handle one and the same keypress.)

| Action | Emacs-style | PC-style (in Xterm) | PC-style (in Rxvt) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Move forward a character | `C-f` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> | `ESC [ C` <kbd>→</kbd> (Right arrow) | `ESC O C` <kbd>→</kbd> |
| Move forward a word | `M-f` <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> | `ESC [ 1 ; 3 C`<sup>1</sup> <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> | `ESC ESC [ C` <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> |
| Scroll forward a page | `C-v` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> | `ESC [ 6 ~` <kbd>Page Down</kbd> | `ESC [ 6 ~` <kbd>Page Down</kbd> |

<sup>1</sup> (This is not in your list, probably because your list isn't exactly "Xterm vs Rxvt" but rather might be "Some 30-year-old terminal vs some other 30-year-old terminal". Still, it does the job of demonstrating that the same physical key needs to be handled in two different ways for a terminal-based app.)

Finally, <kbd>Space</kbd> mimics <kbd>Page Down</kbd> for convenience, as in many other reading-oriented apps (including modern web browsers).